# The cause of differences of "for" loop between list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I've made a "for" loop of list.

```
chosen_subjects = ['physics', 'maths', 'computer science', 'medicine']

for subjects in chosen_subjects:
    print(subjects.title())
```

I've made a "for" loop of dictionary

```
chosen_subjects = {'sarah': 'physics', 'john': 'maths', 'denise': 'computer science', 'william': 'medicine'}

for subjects in chosen_subjects.values():
    print(subjects.title())
```

The outcome of these code are exactly identical.

```
Physics
Maths
Computer Science
Medicine
```

Basically if you guys look at the "for" line of these two "for" loop of list and dictionary, the list of "for" loop DOESN"T NEED the parenthesis prior to colon while the dictionary of "for" loop NEED the parenthesis prior to colon.

What are the programmatical reasons, and why did the python designer make such distinctive difference between list and dictionary when making "for" loop at first?

Comment: `values` is a function, you need parentheses to call it.

Comment: in the first case, you're iterating over the variable `chosen_subjects`. In the second case, you're iterating over the value returned by calling the method `chosen_subjects.values`. You call methods with parens.

Comment: To be specific, this is _not_ a difference in how the "for" loop works. the "for" loop just needs to be given something iterable to iterate over, and you've discovered a couple different ways to get something iterable

Answer (score 2):

For an array the goal is very straight forward:

```
[a, b, c, d, e]
```

You will want the for loop to give you each value in the array.

For a dictionary:

```
{a:"cat", b:"dog", c:"moose"}
```

The desired behavior isn't so obvious. Does the developer want to iterate over each key? `[a, b, c, d]` Or do they want the values? `["cat", "dog", "moose"]`.

The reason for this is because a dictionary doesn't have clear way of iterating over it. So you must specity how you want to iterate. Which is why the `.values()` works. You are getting an array of values from the dictionary.